# Unable to update to BootStrap 4 from BootStrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to update to BootStrap 4 from BootStrap 3 on my localhost.

And I got this result which is from bootstrap 3
[image: unexpected result]

Here is a code which I use to link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

And code for this inline form is here

```
<form class="form-inline">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="staticEmail2" class="sr-only">Email</label>
  <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="staticEmail2" value="email@example.com">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group mx-sm-3">
  <label for="inputPassword2" class="sr-only">Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword2" placeholder="Password">
 </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm identity</button>
</form>
```

But when I put a test file outside from the project folder and link to same CSS file then at that time it gives me result

[image]

Which is expected result

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cached data?

Comment: @Beofett, How to do that?

Comment: Depends on your browser.  In Chrome, if you have dev tools open (f12), you can left-click on the reload button and hold to see additional options.  Click `Empty cache and hard reload` to reload the page with no cached data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear your browser cache. If your problem persists, you need to check whether there is any other CSS changing your styles. If there is no such CSS, you need to check whether there is some Javascript overriding your styles. Switch off Javascript in your browser temporally and if the design is better this way, then after you switch Javascript back on, debug your JS code and see when is it changing your styles.